# How to see this integral is bounded for every positive integer n?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

How to see this integral is bounded for every positive integer $n$?
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{n} \frac{\sin^2(nx/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)} dx$$
Since there is a singular point at $x=0$, I cannot argue the behavior near the origin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See also: [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$\frac{\sin^2(nx/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)}=\frac{1-e^{inx}}{1-e^{ix}}\frac{1-e^{-inx}}{1-e^{-ix}}=\sum_{j,k=0}^{n-1}e^{i(j-k)x},$$ the integral is easily evaluated exactly (it is equal to $2\pi$).